# Yii2 Validate that a table record entry does not exist in another table

Tags: validation, yii2

I  am developing a system in yii2 that validates that a national_ID  entry does not belong to a dead person. So I have a table registration1 and deathregister table. I wanted that when I make an entry in the registration1 it should validate that the Id number entered DOES NOT EXIST in table deathregister.

Currently I have this code which is only validating that the record exists, the question I wanted help is to customize it to check if record does NOT exist.

```
 ['identitynumber', 'exist', 'targetClass' => Deathregister::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['nationalidnum' => 'idnum'],'message'=>'The ID number Supplied Belongs to the Dead'],
```

Comment: I think you need custom validator in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As  Bizley suggest, you should do it manually. I think what you need is something like this. You can run a custom validator which will add something to errors or not (based on empty errors array it considers validity)

```
public function rules()
{
    return  [
        ['identitynumber', 'notExistsValidator'],
    ];
}


public function notExistsValidator()
{
    if(!Deathregister::findOne(['nationalidnum' => $this->identitynumber])->exists())
     {
        $this->addError('nationalidnum', 'The ID number Supplied Belongs to the Dead');
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks too for your wonderful support. I followed your example too and in this combination I succeeded. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As '`exist`' is used for availability, the '`unique`' validator checks to see if the input value in a table column is unique.
As before `targetClass`, `targetAttribute`, `filter` is valid for unique.
**Note**: It only works with Active Record model attributes

But you can also use the following methods:
**Inline Validators**:

```
return [
    ['identitynumber', 'unique', 
      'targetClass' => Deathregister::className(), 
      'targetAttribute' => ['nationalidnum' => 'idnum'],
      'message'=>'The ID number Supplied Belongs to the Dead'
      /*Also, if validation of one attribute depends on the value of another attribute */
      // 'when' => function ($model) {
      //         if (condition) {
      //             return $this->addError('identitynumber', Yii::t('user', 'The ID number Supplied Belongs to the Dead')); 
      //          }
      //         return false;
      //       }
    ],
];
```

**Example2:**

```
return [
    // validatorMethod()
    ['identitynumber', 'validatorMethod'],
    // or
    ['identitynumber', function ($attribute, $params) {
        if(!Deathregister::findOne(['nationalidnum' => $this->$attribute])->exists()) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'The ID number Supplied Belongs to the Dead.');
        }
    }],
];


// validatorMethod()
public function ValidatorMethod($attribute, $params)
{
    if(!Deathregister::findOne(['nationalidnum' => $this->$attribute])->exists()) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'The ID number Supplied Belongs to the Dead');
    }
}

/** Or */
// public function validatorMethod()
// {
      // if(!Deathregister::findOne(['nationalidnum' => $this->identitynumber])->exists())
            # code ...
//     }
// }
```

You can also extend the class (**Standalone Validators**)
It is better to refer to this [page](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation) and this [page](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators).
[Link2](https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/input-validation/)

**Note**:If you want to make sure a rule is always applied, you may configure the `skipOnEmpty` and/or `skipOnError` properties to be false in the rule declarations.

Comment: @Bizley, many thanks I used the inline validators as you explained and gave example above and it worked like a charm. Much appreciated and below is the line of code that solved the problem:      <code>   ['identitynumber', 'unique',  'targetClass' => Deathregister::className(),  'targetAttribute' => ['nationalidnum' => 'idnum'],
              'message'=>'The ID number Supplied Belongs to the Dead' ],  </code>

Comment: @Donaman86, was happy to be able to help. 
wish you luck.